# Add colorbar to python 3D/2D quiver plot

Tags: matplotlib, colorbar

I am very confused about how to add color bar to my 3D/2D vector fields.
My source code is below:

```
import copy
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

import fieldmap_utils

data = {}
dot = {
       "ampX":0,
       "ampY":0,    
       "ampZ":0,
       "phaseX":0,
       "phaseY":0,
       "phaseZ":0,
       }
location = {
            "X":[],
            "Y":[],
            "Z":[]
           }

def buildFrame(origin, orientation, length):
    body = np.dot(orientation, length).tolist()
    temp = origin.copy()
    for x in body:
        temp.append(x)
    return temp




dic = fieldmap_utils.load_single_ampphase("EM averaged.csv")
lst = list(dic.index.get_level_values('freq (hz)').unique())
lst.sort()

print("List of available frequencies: ")
for each_freq in lst:
    print(each_freq,end = " ")

print()

freq = input("Enter selected frequency: ")
dic = dic[dic.index.get_level_values('freq (hz)') == int(freq)]




for index, row in dic.iterrows():
    # Looks like this:
    #   data[(x,y,z)] = {"ampX":0,,"ampY":0,"ampZ":0,"phaseX":0,"phaseY":0,"phaseZ":0}
    data[(index[4][0], index[4][1], index[4][2])] = copy.deepcopy(dot)


for index, row in dic.iterrows():
    if (index[7] == "TARGET-X"):
        data[(index[4][0], index[4][1], index[4][2])]["ampX"] = row['ampl']
        data[(index[4][0], index[4][1], index[4][2])]["phaseX"] = row['phase_deg']
    if (index[7] == "TARGET-Y"):
        data[(index[4][0], index[4][1], index[4][2])]["ampY"] = row['ampl']
        data[(index[4][0], index[4][1], index[4][2])]["phaseY"] = row['phase_deg']
    if (index[7] == "TARGET-Z"):
        data[(index[4][0], index[4][1], index[4][2])]["ampZ"] = row['ampl']
        data[(index[4][0], index[4][1], index[4][2])]["phaseZ"] = row['phase_deg']


colorMap = cm.get_cmap('Greys')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
ax3D = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1, projection = '3d')
axX = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
axY = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 3)
axZ = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 4)

positions = list(data.keys())
xloc = set()
yloc = set()
zloc = set()
for each_position in positions:
    xloc.add(each_position[0])
    yloc.add(each_position[1])
    zloc.add(each_position[2])

xlst = list(xloc)
ylst = list(yloc)
zlst = list(zloc)

xlst.sort()
ylst.sort()
zlst.sort()

print("Unique X coordinates:")
for each_x in xlst:
    print(each_x,end = " ")
print()
sliceX = int(input("Enter X slice position: "))

print("Unique Y coordinates:")
for each_y in xlst:
    print(each_y,end = " ")
print()
sliceY = int(input("Enter Y slice position: "))

print("Unique Z coordinates:")
for each_z in zlst:
    print(each_z,end = " ")
print()
sliceZ = int(input("Enter Z slice position: "))

scale = 500
for position in positions:
    x, y, z = position
    u, v, w = data[position]["ampX"]*scale, data[position]["ampY"]*scale, data[position]["ampZ"]*scale

    # orientation = [[data[position]["ampX"], 0, 0],
    #                [0, data[position]["ampY"], 0],
    #                [0, 0, data[position]["ampZ"]]]
    # x, y, z, u, v, w = buildFrame([position[0], position[1], position[2]], orientation, 5000)
    ax3D.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w)
    if x == sliceX:
        axX.quiver(y, z, v, w)
    if y == sliceY:
        axY.quiver(x, z, u, w)
    if z == sliceZ:
        axZ.quiver(x, y, u, v)

#, cmap = colorMap

ax3D.view_init(azim=50, elev=25)
ax3D.set_xlabel('X')
ax3D.set_ylabel('Y')
ax3D.set_zlabel('Z')
ax3D.set_xlim([-275, 300])
ax3D.set_ylim([-275, 450])
ax3D.set_zlim([0, 500])


axX.set_title('Looking from X-axis')
axX.set_xlabel('Y')
axX.set_ylabel('Z')
axX.set_xlim([-275, 425])
axX.set_ylim([0, 500])

axY.set_title('Looking from Y-axis')
axY.set_xlabel('X')
axY.set_ylabel('Z')
axY.set_xlim([-275, 300])
axY.set_ylim([0, 500])


axZ.set_title('Looking from Z-axis')
axZ.set_xlabel('X')
axZ.set_ylabel('Y')
axZ.set_xlim([-275, 300])
axZ.set_ylim([-275, 450])

# plt.savefig('demo', dpi = 1200)

plt.show()
```

The code isn't optimized or perfect, and it is only used as a demo.

However, I am really confused about how should I add 1 color bar to the 3 2D quiver plots.

I have read through some documentations of matlibplot, but I still don't have a decent idea of how to add color bar. I tried to use the same method that I did in scatter plot, but it didn't work out either.

Thank you guys for helping!

Comment: What's the color you want to map?

Comment: Maybe from yellow to red? As long as the color changes based on the magnitude of the vector, it should be good. By the way, thanks for the reply!

Comment: Ah, so you first want to actually colorize the arrows. I think that is an important piece of information, not present in the question.

Comment: You mean color the arrow based on its magnitude? I will give it a try. However, how should I add the color bar? Should I do `plt.colorbar(fig)` ? That always gives me an error...

Comment: As long as you do not have any colors to map, it does not make sense (and is pretty hard) to add a colorbar. Once you have colorized your arrows, adding a colorbar is the next step. So do you need help with colorizing arrows? Or would you like to show your code for colorized arrows and as for help with adding a colorbar to thoose?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I can color my quvier by doing `axX.quiver(y, z, v, w, color = Some_Color)`. However, I don't quite know how to change the color based on the magnitude of the vector...? Do you need to normalize the data before giving it a color?

Comment: Well, a reasonable way would be to use a colormap and a normalization. I cannot run your code, so if you need help with that, please provide a [mcve] (this should be possible to do in something like 15-20 lines).

Comment: I have just color all my vectors by using `Normalize()` and `color = colorMap(normX(data))`. I wonder if you know how to add color bar to the graph? I am constantly getting error like `AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'autoscale_None'`, when I call `plt.colorbar(fig)`...

Comment: So first, `plt.colorbar(fig)` does not work, because the argument to `colorbar` needs to be mappable, not a figure. That is, the colorbar simply needs to know what to show and it cannot guess from a figure alone. Once you have a norm and a colormap you can create a `sc = ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)` and supply it to the colorbar, `plt.colorbar(sc)`. Before you still need to set the mappable's array, in this case it can probably be empty `sc.set_array([])`.

Comment: Thanks for replying to this. I have now solved the problem. Thank you very much XD!

Comment: If you think your solution is relevant for other people (and hasn't been given elsewhere already) you may answer your own question.